# How can one prevent a git branch from being merged into another?

Tags: git, version-control, workflow, bitbucket, githooks

In a common (git-based) development workflow, one maintains a `master` branch and a `next` (or `dev`) branch which is used for testing purposes:

- feature branches begin from `master` and are merged into `next` for testing. If deemed stable, feature branches can be merged into `master`.
- `master` is periodically merged into `next`
- `next` is periodically rewound (say, after a release).
- **The `next` branch should never be merged into the `master` branch**

It would be useful to be able to **automatically prevent merges of `next` into `master`**, either directly or via another branch based on `next`. **How can one accomplish this using git?**

Note: as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381105/git-hook-to-prevent-an-experimental-branch-pushed-to-a-release-or-master-branch), it is possible to use git hooks to prevent these types of merges on a remote repository one has full access to. However, this is (presumably) not possible with services like BitBucket or GitHub, so I seek a solution that works with a local repository, or one which can be used with a remote repository that one only has limited administrative access to.

Comment: Why don't you install the hook locally?

Comment: The hook in the link is an update hook, which only makes sense for a remote repository. Perhaps it's simple, but how would one translate that into a local hook?

Comment: This seems like a fantastic question and is one I need an answer to too. It's extraordinary and quite troubling that it doesn't have far more attention and a hook based answer, as it seem crucial to safe use of this workflow. I'm wanting to do this having cost my team a pile of time and annoyance in exactly the way the OP describes (with the "via another branch" variant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you really want to use Github/Bitbucket, then don't give anyone write access to your repo. Only accept pull requests. That way, you can check the request which merges it contains and reject them if you see something that you won't want.

A way to automate this is to create a local repo, add a hook which does the checks and then pull the pull request into the new local "validation" repo (which shouldn't be your normal work repo, so you can always throw it away).